# SQL - group by custom time range/interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way in SQL to group by a custom time intervall. For example: i want to count rows and group by day. The difficulty is that the day is from 05-23 instead of 0-24 oclock.

Comment: What does "05-23" mean?

Comment: So what about when things happen between 23:00 and 05:00 the following day?

Comment: first, what did you try?  what is the table structure, .....

Comment: Hi Lamu, this is exactly the Problem. I Need an interval between 23 oclock today and 05 oclock tomorrow. Then i want to get the amount of rows COUNT(*). I want to use the intervall as a Group for all my data rows.

Comment: So you want 2 groups per day? Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Data:
Structur: id,timestamp

For example car Speed control. One datarow for every car that was to fast.
id;timestamp
0;2020-01-01 09:00:00
0;2020-01-01 09:45:00
0;2020-01-01 11:00:00
0;2020-01-02 00:15:00
0;2020-01-02 03:30:00
0;2020-01-02 04:00:00
0;2020-01-02 05:00:00
0;2020-01-02 06:00:00

My Goal is it to Count and group all rows every day from 09:00 - next day 04:00 oclock. 2020-01-01 09:00:00 - 2020-01-02 04:00:00 then 2020-01-02 09:00:00 - 2020-01-03 04:00:00

Answer (score 1):

If you want the day to start at 5:00 a.m., then subtract 5 hours:

```
select convert(date, dateadd(hour, -5, datecol)) as dte, count(*)
from t
group by convert(date, dateadd(hour, -5, datecol));
```

Comment: Very good aproach - thank you. But is it possible to group from 23 Uhr today until 05 Uhr tomorrow. and then Count the rows?

Comment: @phpler . . . Add a `where` close to filter out all the times that you do not want.  Then this code will work.

Comment: I don't get the idea. Can i get a explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select
  iif(cast(datecol as time) between '05:00:00' and '22:59:59', cast(datecol as date), '9999-12-31'),
  count(*) as day_count
from t
group by iif(cast(datecol as time) between '05:00:00' and '22:59:59', cast(datecol as date), '9999-12-31');
```

EDIT: To avoid the wordiness it could be DRY'ed out using CROSS APPLY

```
select
  new_day.day_dt,
  count(*) as day_count
from 
  t
  cross apply
  (select iif(cast(datecol as time) between '05:00:00' and '22:59:59', cast(datecol as date), '9999-12-31') day_dt) new_day
group by
  new_day.day_dt;
```

Comment: I highly advise against using ordinal position in the `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` clause. Changing the order of the columns breaks the query very easily. Repeat the expression, or define the expression in a subquery/`VALUES` clause, and then reference the column from there by it's alias.

Comment: @Larnu you're correct it's not right.  Sorry that's SAS psuedo-SQL and not SQL Server.  I think ordinal position only works in ORDER BY.  Should I edit it?