# How to group by data by a 24 hours interval start from 5:00 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| user | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-02-28 | 08:00 |
| 01 | 2023-02-28 | 09:15 |
| 01 | 2023-02-28 | 04:20 |
| 01 | 2023-02-27 | 19:00 |

I want to select first and last time for each user per day. But the day is not start from 0:00 to 24:00 but 5:00 to 5:00.

So the expected query result of above data should be

| user | date | firsttime | lasttime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-02-28 08:00 | 2023-02-28 09:15 |
| 01 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-02-27 19:00 | 2023-02-27 04:20 |

How to do that? I think I need to first find which date the time belong to,like

```
select 
    user,
    convert(datetime, date + ' ' + time, 121) as time,
    case 
        when convert(datetime, date + ' ' + time, 121) > convert(datetime, date + ' ' + "05:00:00", 121)   
            then convert(datetime, date, 101) 
        when convert(datetime, date + ' ' + time, 121) <= convert(datetime, date + ' ' + "05:00:00", 121) 
            then convert(datetime, date, 101) - 1 
    end as Belongdate 
from 
    Table
```

Then I group the result set by user and belongdate to get the result. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: [SQL - group by custom time range/interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376714/sql-group-by-custom-time-range-interval) ?

Comment: Something that happens at 05:00 exactly can't be both at the start of today and the end of yesterday. You need to pick if the start or the end is exclusive.

Comment: (Also, why are you storing date and time in separate columns? Are they `date` and `time` or both `datetime`? It would actually be easier if you didn't.)

Comment: `DATE_BUCKET` makes this a little easier, in some way, in 2022+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
    (
        [id] INT
      , [dd] DATE
      , [tm] TIME
    ) ;
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
    ( 01, '2023-02-28', '08:00' )
  , ( 01, '2023-02-28', '09:15' )
  , ( 01, '2023-02-28', '04:20' )
  , ( 01, '2023-02-27', '19:00' ) ;

DECLARE @StartofDd TIME = '05:00' ;

;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  [id]
              , [dd]
              , [tm]
              , IIF([tm] < @StartofDd, DATEADD ( dd, -1, [dd] ), [dd]) AS [ndd]
              , SUM ( IIF([dd] != IIF([tm] < @StartofDd, DATEADD ( dd, -1, [dd] ), [dd]), 1, 0)) OVER ( PARTITION BY IIF([tm] < @StartofDd, DATEADD ( dd, -1, [dd] ), [dd])) AS [chk]
        FROM    @Data
    )
SELECT      [id]
          , [ndd]
          , IIF(MIN ( [chk] ) = 0, CAST (MIN ( [ndd] ) AS DATETIME) + CAST (MIN ( [tm] ) AS DATETIME), CAST (MIN ( [ndd] ) AS DATETIME) + CAST (MAX ( [tm] ) AS DATETIME)) AS [firsttime]
          , IIF(MIN ( [chk] ) = 0, CAST (MAX ( [ndd] ) AS DATETIME) + CAST (MAX ( [tm] ) AS DATETIME), CAST (MAX ( [ndd] ) AS DATETIME) + CAST (MIN ( [tm] ) AS DATETIME)) AS [lasttime]
FROM        CTE
GROUP BY    [id]
          , [ndd] ;
```

Edit: This solution assumes date & time are of date and time datatypes, respectively. @Aaron Bertrand made no such assumption so that's probably the way to go. Also, this assumes you want the date, for the records where time < 5:00, to be updated to previous day (unsure if it's accurate, but it's what shows in the expected)

Answer (score 3):

If the columns `date` and `time` are of types `date` and `time`:

```
SELECT [user], 
       date = effdate, 
       firsttime = MIN(dt), 
       lasttime  = MAX(dt)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT [user], 
      effdate = dateadd(DAY, case 
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, time) < 5 then -1 ELSE 0 END, date),
      dt = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, time), convert(datetime, date))
    FROM dbo.[TableA]
  ) AS agg
  GROUP BY [user], effdate;
```

If both columns are `datetime`:

```
SELECT [user], 
       date = CONVERT(date, effdate), 
       firsttime = MIN(dt), 
       lasttime  = MAX(dt)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT [user], 
      effdate = dateadd(DAY, case 
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, time) < 5 then -1 ELSE 0 END, date),
      dt = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, time), date)
    FROM dbo.[TableB]
  ) AS agg
  GROUP BY [user], effdate;
```

If you stored a single value in a single datetime column (as you should):

```
SELECT [user], 
  date = CONVERT(date, effdate), 
  firsttime = MIN(dt), 
  lasttime  = MAX(dt)
FROM 
(
  SELECT [user], dt, 
    effdate = dateadd(DAY, case 
      WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, dt) < 5 then -1 ELSE 0 END, dt)
  FROM dbo.[TableC]
) AS agg
GROUP BY [user], CONVERT(date, effdate);
```

All three examples are demonstrated in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sa_S_FqJ).

Comment: pretty cool approach. One thing I noticed, and I question the OP for it is, for records where time < 5:00, should the output date reflect previous day or the current day. His expected is showing that date to be of previous day. Strange, but unsure if that's the req or just an oversight when listing expectation.

Comment: @007 Seemed to me like the row for `2023-02-28`, `04:20` belonged to the previous day, and I think that matches the description, but without a proper table and _real_ sample data / desired results, any of our guesses might be correct.

Answer (score -2):

- convert date and time into datetime
- substract 5:00 hours every time to normalize
- convert to date_normalized
- group by date_normalized

  ```
    SELECT
       CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME,date_value+' '+time_value,121)-CONVERT(DATETIME,'5:00') AS DATE)
         AS date_normalized,
  ```

Comment: If `date` and `time` are in fact `date` and `time` types, `Msg 402 Level 16 State 1 / 
The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: The edit [didn't fix the error](https://dbfiddle.uk/uW0YMazZ).